# Rails erb check if exist and do each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, conditional-statements

On one erb document I have an array that may not be defined. So I check for the existence and if it exists I iterate over like so :

```
<% if defined? my_array %>
  <% my_array.each do |item| %>
    <%# do stuff %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And I wanted to know if I could have on one line the condition and the loop.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: I think that what you have already is perfectly readable and doesn't create any problems.  Why do you want to change it?  Coding isn't a contest for who can have the least lines of code.

Comment: Yes I know, I just thought that checking if I can iterate over a variable and then do the iteration was a little bit redundant...

Comment: I don't think it's redundant.  Testing whether it exists and then iterating over it are two totally different things.  Redundancy is when you do the same thing twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better way is to initialize the array from the controller if possible, for example

```
@my_array ||= []
```

This way the `.each` call will still work but won't loop because the array is empty, and so you won't need to check it.

Comment: do you think such assignment can be done from within the view ?

Comment: it could, you could use a dedicated line for this statement `my_array ||= []`, or do something  like `(my_array || []).each`

Comment: If it's a local variable, rather than an instance variable, you can't say `my_array ||= []` because it will explode if it's not defined (unlike instance variables, which return nil if they're not defined).  You'd need to say `my_array = [] unless defined?(my_array)`

Answer (score 1):

You could call `#try` on the each block. This would require adding little code, but keep in mind that [using try is considered by some to be a code smell](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2011/06/28/do-or-do-not-there-is-no-try/).

```
<% my_array.try(:each) do |item| %>
  <%# do stuff %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the fact that `nil.to_a` is `[]`, and `Array#to_a` just returns itself, unaltered.

```
<% my_array.to_a.each do |item| %>
  <%# do stuff %>
<% end %>
```

But it depends what is "may not exist", I assume that means "may be `nil`".
`false.to_a` will not work, for instance.

Comment: @Nobe4 well you got the point, you need to know the possible types :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't find it very idiomatic, but you could do this:

```
<% my_array.each do |item| %>
  <%# do stuff %>
<% end if defined? my_array %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `&.` is the way to go

```
<% my_array&.each do |item| %>
  <%# do stuff %>
<% end %>
```